# error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<float>::push_back(std::vector<float>&) const'

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

I am trying to copy map (m) values into a vector (v)

The map is declared this way:

```
const map<int, vector<float> >& m = ....;
```

I tried this:

```
const vector<float>& v;
for(auto elem : m)
  v.push_back(elem.second);
```

I get this error:

**error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector::push_back(std::vector&) const'**

Comment: Yes, it is constant, so what am I missing? 
(I am coming from python background)

Comment: 1) You are trying to modify `v` that is `const`. 2) You are trying to push `vector<float>`s 
 into `v`, but `v` contains `float`s

Comment: actuly the const reference is diffrenet with reference to const. we can change the const reference value;

Comment: `const` in c++ means that the object is complete immutable. Adding things to the vector would be modifying it, thus not possible with something that's `const`.

Comment: `v` is const! so how you want to modify it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of what you are doing is a little unclear but if you'd like to make a `vector<float>` to hold all the values in all the vectors in the `map`, you could do that, but you can't `push_back` a `vector<float>` directly, which is one of the reasons why you get the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector::push_back(std::vector&) const'
```

You can either `push_back` the `float` values one-by-one - or use the `vector::insert` member function to insert *all* of the elements in one go (which it looks like you are trying to do).

The other reason is that `v` is `const` which means that after it's been initialized, you can't make changes to it.

Some notes:

- You've created both the `map` and the `vector` as `const&`s. This works and extends the lifetime of the temporary `map` and `vector` that you create this way - but being `const` you can't change any of them. I suggest that you remove the reference on at least the `vector` and also make it non-`const` to be able to fill it up.

Example:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    const std::map<int, std::vector<float>> m { {1, {2,3,4}} };

    std::vector<float> v;

    for(auto& elem : m) {
        // insert the vector values from this map-entry at the end of `v`
        v.insert(v.end(), elem.second.begin(), elem.second.end());
    }
}
```

Note `auto& elem` instead of `auto elem`. The latter *copies* the data (which may be expensive) while `auto& elem` takes it by reference.

Using structured bindings, the filling loop would look like this:

```
    for(auto&[first, second] : m) {
        v.insert(v.end(), second.begin(), second.end());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your map type is: `int, vector<float>`
it means your values are type of `vector` of `floats`.
your vector have float type.
you can't push_back vector of float in one element of your vector.
you need to do this.

```
vector<float> v;
for(auto elem : m)
{
    for(auto f : elem.second)
        v.push_back(f);
}
```

or something like that depends on how you want to use your values.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to push a vector to a vector, which doesn't make sense. An object can't be an element of itself.

Change it to:

```
const map<int, float>& m = ....;
```

Or

```
for(auto elem : m)
{
   int i = 0;

   while(i < elem.second.size())
   {
      v.push_back(elem.second[i]);

      i += 1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you try to push VECTOR to vector u need Vector of Vector for this to work
your element is vector and variable v is a vector u need vector<vector>